# Svelte include dynamically imported components in build folder

Tags: svelte

I am following the example [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/16b375da9b39417dae837b5006799cb4?version=3.25.0) to try to load components.

```
onMount(async () => {
    await sleep(1000); // simulate network delay
    Thing = (await import('./Thing.svelte')).default;
});
```

It obviously works in the REPL but when I try it in my dev environment I get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:5000/build/Thing.svelte
```

It seems that Svelte isn't including the component in the build folder? There must be something I am missing?

Comment: As far as I know, the repl only simulates lazy loading and doesn't hit the network. What are you using for building your app? Do you see the generated bundle for Thing.svelte in the build summary or in the build folder?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add `inlineDynamicImports: true` to the output object in the rollup.config.js